# Method level generic return types in interfaces

Tags: java, generics, interface

Do method level generics in interfaces (for return types) ever make sense? Do they have any use? Example:-

```
public interface ABX { 
    public <T> T fx(String p);
}
```

I could simply make the generic class-level like so

```
public interface ABX<T> { 
    public T fx(String p);
}
```

Is there any situation at all where I would want the generic to be method-level in interfaces/abstract classes (for return types).

Comment: The example you've given is basically never useful *anywhere* except as a kludge, because there's no context for the return type inside the method. Such a method can only return `null` to pass static type checking.

Comment: @Radiodef but the implementations of the first interface could define concrete return types.

Comment: No, they can't. Declaring a type parameter on a method makes the method itself polymorphic. The code which calls the method is where the type is defined, not the implementation.

Comment: @Radiodef  see http://ideone.com/3Jn7Ab

Comment: That's not actually safe to do. http://ideone.com/U2cCDK The compiler is already giving you a warning about it. Overriding in that way is not parameterizing the method, it's taking advantage of the way that overrides work with erasure. (You can always override a generic method with a non-generic one, which is allowed for backwards-compatibility, but bypasses the type checking features of generics.)

Comment: @Radiodef  that was very well explained. Thanks.

Comment: Here's another snippet which explains how it works in a more clear manner. http://ideone.com/ofQVOc We can override a generic method with its erasure, so that non-generic versions of Java can extend generic classes. (Don't ask me why this was thought to be important when they came up with it. Personally I think it's more confusing than anything.)

Comment: @Radiodef so if I don't want the caller do decide the return type, the generic should always be class-level right?

Answer (score 2):

Method level generics certainly do have utility. But you have to bind the generic type parameter somehow so typically such a method will have a generic argument, like Class, and then return a generic value. Your example doesn't do this, so it's difficult to see the value of the generic type parameter.

You can see examples of them all over the place - the ones I come across most are in the Jackson databinding class ObjectMapper - https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html, such as

```
<T> T readValue(InputStream is, Class<T> returnType)
```

So, the value here is that ObjectMapper is *not* a generically typed class but it allows me to bind *any* class (provided it can understand the class and how to set its various properties based on the input). The important point there is that you only need a single instance of ObjectMapper for an entire application, you don't need one for every type of object you might need to databind.